# Context Menu on right click

Tags: vmware-clarity

We have been using vSphere, and through that we discovered Clarity, which we are migrating our Angular projects over to.

Something I've noticed in vSphere is - when you right click something in the tree view (to the right), a context menu comes out. Is there any support or tips for creating a context menu? I couldn't see anything in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarity itself does not support this, and it is generally against our recommendations due to changing the default browser behaviors. If you decide to use a feature like this you'll have to include or create a different Angular module for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution myself - looks like it's a [**telerik context menu**](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/menus/contextmenu/)